# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall FizzBuzz::FizzBuzz(void)" referenced in function _wmain

Tags: c++

I feel like this is something silly I'm missing. I've searched a bit but am not finding much in terms of a solution for this. I've tried the few solutions I've found online (Changing type from Console to Windows to none, etc). I've had no luck with anything so any comments are appreciated.

Note: I have tried other things (and searched on Stack Overflow) but haven't had luck :/

Here is my source:

Main.cpp

```
#include "FizzBuzz.h"
#include <tchar.h>
int _tmain(){

FizzBuzz f;
//Main loop
while (f.isRunning())
{
    f.UserInput();
}

std::system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

FizzBuzz.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>

class FizzBuzz
{
    int FizzBuzz::fbArray[10][10];
    bool FizzBuzz::running;
    int FizzBuzz::score;
    int FizzBuzz::guesses;

    FizzBuzz::FizzBuzz(){
        fbArray[10][10] = {};
        running = true;
        score = 0;
        guesses = 0;
    }

    bool FizzBuzz::isRunning(void)
    {
        return running;
    }
    void FizzBuzz::setRunning(bool var)
    {
        running = var;
    }
    int FizzBuzz::getScore(void)
    {
        return score;
    }
    void FizzBuzz::setScore(int var)
    {
        score = var;
    }
    int FizzBuzz::getGuesses(void)
    {
        return guesses;
    }
    void FizzBuzz::setGuesses(int var)
    {
        guesses = var;
    }

    void FizzBuzz::UserInput(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter which you would like to do: '1' for the     Guessing Game, '2' for generating an array, '-1' to quit!" << std::endl;
        int choice;
        std::cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            int row, column;
            populateArray(fbArray);
            validateFizzBuzz();
            std::cout << "Enter a row and column below, -1 to exit on     either." << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Please enter a row: ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Please enter a column: ";
            std::cin >> column;

            if (row == -1 || column == -1)
            {
                displayScore();
            }
            else{
                score += FizzBuzzCalc(row, column); //Add score to current score
                std::cout << "You got: " << score << " points for that guess." << std::endl;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            populateArray(fbArray);
            printArray(fbArray);
            break;
        case -1:
            std::cout << "Thanks for playing!" << std::endl;
            running = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }


    }
    int FizzBuzz::FizzBuzzCalc(int row, int column)
    {
        guesses++;
        if (getFizzBuzz(fbArray[row][column]) == "FizzBuzz")
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }


    }
    void FizzBuzz::displayScore()
    {
        std::cout << "You scored: " << score << " in " << guesses << " guesses!" << std::endl;
    }
    bool FizzBuzz::validateFizzBuzz()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            {
                if (getFizzBuzz(fbArray[i][j]) == "FizzBuzz")
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        if (count > 20 || count < 6)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 11; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 11; l++)
                {
                    if (count > 20)
                    {
                        if (getFizzBuzz(fbArray[k][l]) == "FizzBuzz")
                        {
                            fbArray[k][l] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (count < 6)
                    {
                        if (getFizzBuzz(fbArray[k][l]) == "Fizz")
                        {
                            fbArray[k][l] = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;



    }
    //Populates an array with numbers randomly between 1-100
    void FizzBuzz::populateArray(int arrayIn[10][10])
    {
        srand(time(NULL));

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            {
                arrayIn[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //Prints a 2x2 array
    void FizzBuzz::printArray(int arrayin[10][10]){
        for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w < 10; w++)
            {
                printf("%i,", arrayin[h][w]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    //Prompts user to enter an array of numbers, seperated by commas, then passes this to getFizzBuzzArray and prints them to the screen.
    void FizzBuzz::fizzBuzzArrayPrompt()
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter numbers in a comma seperated list (EX:'8,9,10,11,12')";
        std::string str;
        std::cin >> str;
        std::istringstream ss(str);
        std::string token;

        while (std::getline(ss, token, ',')){
            if (getFizzBuzzArray(std::stoi(token)) == "")
            {
                std::cout << "Invalid FizzBuzz Number: " << token << " ";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "Output: Number: " << token << " - " << getFizzBuzzArray(std::stoi(token)) << " ";
            }
        }


    }
    //Prompts the user to enter a number and then writes the FizzBuzz to the screen (from getFizzBuzz())
    void FizzBuzz::fizzBuzzPrompt()
    {
        int number;
        std::cout << "Please enter number, then press Enter key: ";
        std::cin >> number;

        std::string str = getFizzBuzz(number);
        if (getFizzBuzz(number) == "")
        {
            fizzBuzzPrompt();
        }
        else{
            std::cout << std::endl << "Output: Number: " << number << " - " << str << " ";
        }
    }
    //getFizzBuzzArray returns the respective fizzBuzz String to the array function - this was made special for the function.
    //getFizzBuzz so it could re-call for the user to re-prompt. Gets this from string format (converted)
    std::string FizzBuzz::getFizzBuzzArray(int number)
    {
        if (!(number % 2) && !(number % 3) && !(number % 5) || number == 1 || number == -1){
            std::cout << "Please enter a number value, not a character!" << std::endl;
            return "";
        }
        else{
            if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0)
            {
                return "FizzBuzz";
            }
            else
            {
                if (number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    return "Fizz";
                }
                else if (number % 5 == 0)
                {
                    return "Buzz";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }




    }
    //Gets a single Fizzbuzz string from a number
    std::string FizzBuzz::getFizzBuzz(int number)
    {

        if (!(number % 2) && !(number % 3) && !(number % 5) || number == 1 || number == -1){
            std::cout << "Please enter a number value, not a character!" << std::endl;
            return "";
        }
        else{
            if (number % 3 == 0 && number % 5 == 0)
            {
                return "FizzBuzz";
            }
            else
            {
                if (number % 3 == 0)
                {
                    return "Fizz";
                }
                else if (number % 5 == 0)
                {
                    return "Buzz";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Please enter another number!" << std::endl;
                    return "";
                }
            }
        }





    }
};
```

And FizzBuzz.h

```
#ifndef FIZZ_BUZZ_H
#define FIZZ_BUZZ_H

#include <string>

class FizzBuzz
{

    public:
    FizzBuzz::FizzBuzz();
    bool FizzBuzz::isRunning(void);
    void FizzBuzz::setRunning(bool var);
    int FizzBuzz::getScore();
    void FizzBuzz::setScore(int var);
    int FizzBuzz::getGuesses();
    void FizzBuzz::setGuesses(int var);
    void FizzBuzz::UserInput();
    int FizzBuzz::FizzBuzzCalc(int row, int column);
    void FizzBuzz::displayScore();
    bool FizzBuzz::validateFizzBuzz();
    void FizzBuzz::populateArray(int arrayIn[10][10]);
    void FizzBuzz::printArray(int arrayin[10][10]);
    void FizzBuzz::fizzBuzzArrayPrompt();
    void FizzBuzz::fizzBuzzPrompt();

    private:
    std::string FizzBuzz::getFizzBuzzArray(int number);
    std::string FizzBuzz::getFizzBuzz(int number);
};




#endif FIZZ_BUZZ_H
```

Comment: From the .cpp remove `class FizzBuzz {` and `};`, and from the .h remove the `FizzBuzz::` prefixes.

Comment: This was exactly it, thanks so much! Kinda obvious after looking at it that way.. Lol